# @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.0 requires typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.6.0' but 2.6.2 was found instead

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

How to overcome this issue for the already created Angular project? I Would like to use 2.6.2 Typescript

```
@angular/compiler-cli@5.2.0 requires typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.6.0' but 2.6.2 was found instead.
Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.
Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.
    npm install typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.6.0'
To disable this warning run "ng set warnings.typescriptMismatch=false".
The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'*
```

Comment: Just run `npm install typescript`. Ignore the warning.

Comment: thanks, by running `npm install typescript` it installed the version 2.4.2

Comment: Try `npm install typescript@latest --peer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is clear... your angular CLI version require a Typescript lower version.

You need to downgrade your Typescript version.

In your package.json change :

```
"typescript": "^2.6.2",
```

With

```
"typescript": "^2.4.2",
```

and run

```
npm install
```

Comment: I would argue for pinning the version, instead of keeping the caret range, if there's such a strict version requirement coming out of the angular CLI

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable suggestion :)